# Como crear una columna con más de una condición

Tags: python, pandas, where, apply

Tengo este `dataframe` que entrega a la antena con mejor comportamiento la calificación "excelente" si el "rendimiento3" es el más alto. Si hay empate se otoga al que tenga mejor "rendimiento2", y si hay empate al que tenga mejor "rendimiento1".

```
antenas= {'antena' : ['antena A', 'antena B','antena D','antena C','antena D', 'antena E'],
                         'rendimiento1' : [7, 2, 4, 4, 9, 4],
                         'rendimiento2' : [3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1],
                         'rendimiento3' : [13,  8,  6   ,6,19, 12]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(antenas)
```

Intenté creando una función:

```
def maquinas(df):
    if df['Rendimiento3'] == max(df['Rendimiento3']):
      if df['Rendimiento2'] == min(df['Rendimiento2']): 
        return "Excelente"
      elif df['Rendimiento1'] == min(df['Rendimiento1']): 
        return "Excelente"
      else:
        return "Excelente"    
    else:
     return "revisar"
```

Pero al utilizar el apply me da:

> Error int not iterable

Comment: Buen día, no es claro como estás utilizando `apply` (Si en columnas o filas), por favor agrega esa sección de código. Por otra parte, cuando defines `maquinas` tu variable es `df` y al ser igual que el nombre que le pusiste al `dataframe` entonces todas las instancias de `df` dentro de tu función hacen referencia a la fila o la columna del `dataframe` y no puedes hacer `max` o `min` de un único entero, por eso te devuelve el error. También agrega un ejemplo del resultado esperado para comprobar si hemos entendido bien la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Como puse en el comentario, el problema de tu función es el `scope` de tu variable `df` y al llamarse igual que la variable del `dataframe` crees que accedes al `dataframe` pero en realidad estás accediendo a una fila o columna dependiendo el eje (`axis`) que estés utilizando.

Para solucionarlo puedes renombrar la variable de la función `maquina` a `row` de la siguiente forma y recorrer las filas (`axis = 1`):

```
def maquinas(row):
    df.loc[df['Rendimiento3'] == df['Rendimiento3'].max()]
    if row['Rendimiento3'] == max(df['Rendimiento3']):
        if row['Rendimiento2'] == min(df['Rendimiento2']): 
            return "Excelente"
        elif row['Rendimiento1'] == min(df['Rendimiento1']): 
            return "Excelente"
        else:
            return "Excelente"    
    else:
        return "revisar"

df.apply(maquinas, axis=1)
```

Pero la lógica de tu función no es correcta por lo que no te dará el resultado esperado.

Una forma más fácil de hacerlo es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) en cadena para filtrar el `dataframe` original.

Con el siguiente `dataframe` de ejemplo (Agregué dos filas más para que se pueda ver el funcionamiento correcto):

```
     antena  Rendimiento1  Rendimiento2  Rendimiento3
0  antena A             7             3            13
1  antena B             2             2             8
2  antena D             4             2             6
3  antena C             4             4             6
4  antena D             9             5            19
5  antena E             4             1            12
6  antena F             8             5            19
7  antena G             7             2            19
```

Obtenemos primero todas las filas cuyo valor sea igual al máximo de la columna "Rendimiento3":

```
print(df.loc[df['Rendimiento3'] == df['Rendimiento3'].max()])
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
     antena  Rendimiento1  Rendimiento2  Rendimiento3
4  antena D             9             5            19
6  antena F             8             5            19
7  antena G             7             2            19
```

Luego agregamos un nuevo filtro pero ahora con la columna "Rendimiento2":

```
print(df.loc[df['Rendimiento3'] == df['Rendimiento3'].max()].loc[df['Rendimiento2'] == df['Rendimiento2'].max()])
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
     antena  Rendimiento1  Rendimiento2  Rendimiento3
4  antena D             9             5            19
6  antena F             8             5            19
```

Y como ya has de haber adivinado, agregamos un tercer filtro pero ahora para la columna "Rendimiento1":

```
print(df.loc[df['Rendimiento3'] == df['Rendimiento3'].max()].loc[df['Rendimiento2'] == df['Rendimiento2'].max()].loc[df['Rendimiento1'] == df['Rendimiento1'].max()])
```

Que imprime:

```
     antena  Rendimiento1  Rendimiento2  Rendimiento3
4  antena D             9             5            19
```

Ahora, como hemos utilizado varios `loc` en cadena tenemos que utilizar un `loc` digamos "primario" que aplicará todos los otros filtros al `dataframe` original.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

antenas = {'antena' : ['antena A', 'antena B','antena D','antena C','antena D', 'antena E', 'antena F', 'antena G'],
                         'Rendimiento1' : [7, 2, 4, 4, 9, 4, 8, 7],
                         'Rendimiento2' : [3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2],
                         'Rendimiento3' : [13, 8, 6, 6, 19, 12, 19, 19]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(antenas)

# Asignamos "Revisar" a todas las filas
df['Servicio'] = 'Revisar'

# Asignamos "Excelente a la(s) filas que cumplan con todas las condiciones"
df.loc[df.loc[df['Rendimiento3'] == df['Rendimiento3'].max()].loc[df['Rendimiento2'] == df['Rendimiento2'].max()].loc[df['Rendimiento1'] == df['Rendimiento1'].max()].index, 'Servicio'] = 'Excelente'
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
     antena  Rendimiento1  Rendimiento2  Rendimiento3   Servicio
0  antena A             7             3            13    Revisar
1  antena B             2             2             8    Revisar
2  antena D             4             2             6    Revisar
3  antena C             4             4             6    Revisar
4  antena D             9             5            19  Excelente
5  antena E             4             1            12    Revisar
6  antena F             8             5            19    Revisar
7  antena G             7             2            19    Revisar
```

Comment: Excelente Gracia funciona perfecto, sin embargo, si lo que buscara fuese el mínimo para " excelente" y "revisar" para el resto el cambiar max por min no funciona..

Comment: @ManuelDario, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @ManuelDario, no entiendo que quisiste decir o intentaste hacer con `min` pero esa sería una pregunta diferente, por lo que te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta.